# The difference between "adopt" and "use" when they refer to utilizing something

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, synonyms

Both of "adopt" and "use" can represent utilize something.
What is the difference? I feel "adopt" is more formal, but I am not sure of my feelings.

For instance, I am writing an academic paper. Could I use

> We adopt the Jaccard index in our implementation.

Or shall I use

> We use the Jaccard index in our implementation.

I cannot distinguish the difference between the above two sentences and would like to choose
"adopt".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "adopt" does not merely mean to use.  [In order to adopt, you must start using it.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt)

> to **take up** and practice or use

Emphasis mine.

For instance, during the Neolithic, humans used both agriculture and fire, but they only adopted agriculture, since they had long used fire.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! Thank you most sincerely!